# Memory creep as program runs, CGGlyphBitmapCreate (among others)?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-graphics, allocation, heapshot

This is piggybacking off of a broader question yesterday.  I've been use heapshots to pinpoint problems, but they're all in callers that I'm not familiar with.  The methods that I have written myself are not showing up, but CoreGraphics seems to be eating memory like crazy.

I was all set to submit my app this week, but ran into a huge problem. I've been doing a lot of QA, and leak detection and was finishing off the process with heapshot/allocation profiling. Unfortunately, this did not go as planned. The program isn't "leaking" per se, but it is climbing unquestionably.

The best way to explain the program is a math flashcard (first app, learning the ropes, I wanted to make it simple). There's are 5 buttons, 2 Image Views, and 2 UILabels.
I'm banging my head into the wall, and wondering if my design is a problem (short answer: probably), but more concerned about the memory creep that will almost surely not allow me to get into the app store.

So, the process:
The view displays a Home button (for going back to the main menu), a Checkbox (for marking a problem for later), a math problem in a UILabel, and a Get Answer button. When you press get answer, the Answer displays in a second UILabel, and two more buttons (Right and Wrong) appear, and the Get Answer button title changes to "Get Problem". Pressing Get Problem resets us back to the beginning, with a new problem.

I've been using heapshot to find how much memory is being taken up, and I've found that I'm losing between 10-15KB every time I got through one iteration (Pressing "Get Answers" then pressing either "Right" or "Wrong"). The worst offender is the called "CGGlyphBitmapCreate" which I honestly have little knowledge of what it actually is.

Some other notes: The "home" button is a custom button with a .png created in IB. The "marked" button with not text that sits on top of two .pngs that I switch between (via .hidden) depending on the state of the checkbox (I hide one, then display the other, and vice versa).

Call Stack:

```
0 libSystem.B.dylib calloc
1 CoreGraphics CGGlyphBitmapCreate
2 CoreGraphics CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap8
3 CoreGraphics CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap
4 CoreGraphics CGGlyphLockLockGlyphBitmaps
5 libRIP.A.dylib ripc_DrawGlyphs
6 CoreGraphics draw_glyphs
7 CoreGraphics CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances
8 WebCore WebCore::showGlyphsWithAdvances(WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, CGContext*, unsigned short const*, CGSize const*, unsigned long)
9 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawGlyphs(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WebCore::GlyphBuffer const&, int, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, bool) const
10 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawSimpleText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const
11 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const
12 WebKit drawAtPoint(unsigned short const*, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::Font const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, bool, WebCore::BidiStatus*, int)
13 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:drawUnderline:]
14 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:]
15 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:]
16 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:]
17 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:]
18 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:includeEmoji:]
19 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:]
20 UIKit -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:]
21 UIKit -[UILabel drawTextInRect:]
22 UIKit -[UILabel drawRect:]
23 UIKit -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:]
24 QuartzCore -[CALayer drawInContext:]
25 QuartzCore backing_callback(CGContext*, void*)
26 QuartzCore CABackingStoreUpdate_
27 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display_()
28 QuartzCore -[CALayer _display]
29 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display()
30 QuartzCore -[CALayer display]
31 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
32 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
33 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
34 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
35 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
36 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
37 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
38 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
39 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
40 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
41 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
42 UIKit UIApplicationMain
43 MathProb main /Users/test/MathProb/main.m:14
44 MathProb start
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: `CGGlyphBitmapCreate` is, I assume, not called in a vacuum. What's calling it? And what's calling that? Work your way up the call stack until you get to something you recognize.

Comment: What version of iOS (or the Simulator thereof) are you running this on?

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark, but since it's the low-hanging fruit: Are you by any chance saving graphics states and never letting them back out?

Comment: @PeterHosey iOS 5.0, XCode 4.2.  I even tried converting to ACR but it didn't help.

Comment: @Chuck I don't think so, at least not consciously.  I'm not even sure I know how.

Comment: Did you get any solution? i face the same problem. Seems the OS cache the glyph bitmap and didn't release it even when receive memory warning

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NSZombieEnabled set to YES? I believe this may cause false positives. One way to verify you are not seeing an artifact of your development environment is to change to release mode: command+option+R, set run to use release mode. Then, run the app. Now, quickly push the home button twice on the iPad, kill the app, and launch it from the home screen normally. I have seen false positive memory leaks go away when launched in this manner.